# Google App Engine deleted app version comes back

Tags: google-app-engine

I deleted a particular version of an app in google app engine. However, after a while, I noticed the version was still there and I had to delete it again. The following is the admin log of two deletions.

[image]

Anyone knows why? I ask this question because I feel that google app engine does not seem to delete a version. Even after I deleted a version and re-upload, the upload time is too quick for an app about 60m+ in size.

Comment: IIRC The upload tool only uploads a diff of what's changed, so it can be quite quick depending on what is already present.

Comment: Are you deleting a version and then uploading that same version again?

Comment: There was no uploading of the same version during the two deletions. If there was, it should show the uploading between the two deletions in the above admin log